# Ample line bundles and compactificatiions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme over $\mathbb C$ and $L$ an ample line bundle on $X$. Suppose that for every integer $k$, $\dim(H^0(L^k))<\infty$. Then for sufficiently big integers $n$, there is a well-defined immersion of $X$ in the projective space ${\mathbb P}(H^0(L^n)^*)$. Let $X_n$ be the closure of the image of $X$ in this projective space. Is it true that $X_n\simeq X_{n+1}\simeq\cdots$?

Comment: Are you aware that $H^0(L^n)$ may be infinite-dimensional?

Comment: For instance, a scheme is quasi-affine if and only if $\mathcal O_X$ is ample \[Tag [01QE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01QE)\]. But in this case, $H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)$ is only finite-dimensional if $X$ is finite over $\mathbf C$.

Comment: You are right, I have added the finite dimension hypothesis.